# Java - argument mismatch using generics

Tags: java, generics, type-mismatch

I'm having a problem using the add method of ConcurrentLinkedQueue the following error appears:

> method add(Message) in the type ConcurrentLinkedQueue is not
>   applicable for the arguments (Class)

basically it says that the argument 'type' is of the wrong Class (should be of type Message),

I find it odd cause "Request" is an Interface extending the Interface "Message" so 'type' which extends "Request" would be of Type "Message" as well.

is there something i'm missing?

```
package bgu.spl.mics;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MessageBusImpl implements MessageBus {

    private ConcurrentHashMap<String , ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Message>> allQueues = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(); // Mapping from a microService name to it's message-queue
    private ConcurrentHashMap<Message, ArrayList<ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Message>>> messageTypeToSubsribers = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(); // Mapping from a message type to an ArrayList of the message-queues which are subscribed to it      

    @Override // make MicroService @m a subscriber of Request @type
    public void subscribeRequest(Class<? extends Request> type, MicroService m) {
        allQueues.get(m.getName()).add(type);

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply can't work. The generic type you are working with is:

```
private ConcurrentHashMap<String , ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Message>> allQueues
```

So, a Map with String keys and Queue values. But then you are trying to add

```
allQueues.get(m.getName()).add(type); // where type is Class<? extends Request>
```

Thus: the compiler is telling you that you can't add a *Class* object to a Queue that only takes *Message* objects!

Long story short: simply **read** the compiler message; step back and figure what exactly you want to do. Like: why do you *want* to add a *Class* to a queue of *Messages*?!

Besides, there is potential for **another** bug in that code: your get() call there ... what happens when it returns **null**?! How are you making sure that you already **created** a Queue for that specific name?!

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're seeing is because you're not trying to add an *instance* of a Message, but instead you're adding a Class that extends Request. If you were to update the `subscribeRequest(...)` to accept a `Request` instance instead of a `Class<? extends Request>`, I think you'll find it compiles.